# How to visually personalize Google Chrome for development

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using the little setup that [ShimmerCat](https://www.shimmercat.com) provides for web development: SOCKS5 with built-in DNS and private certificate authority. For those of you that don't know how it works, it basically means that once you start your development web server, you invoke the browser using a helper script. This script opens a browser instance with completely separated user directory and configuration. Then it is just a matter of opening the future website as it were already deployed on the Internet, the SOCKS5 and built-in DNS emulation does the magic. For example, if the site is www.my-cool-client-site.com, I just open the locally running version by typing that address in the browser.

It's all very neat and functional, but now we have deployed our real site on the Internet, and as expected everything just looks the same as in my local development setup, **including the address in the browser address bar and the green padlock icon**. More than once now I have found myself banging my head for "a bug" that has turned out to be me confusing the development project with the site already deployed on the Internet. Therefore my question:

Is there a way to personalize a [Google Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) profile in a very obvious way so that I can't confuse my development configuration with the normal configuration that I use to browse the Internet?